# QuerySourceFeature is not working as expected - Mapbox GL

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am looking for a answer that will solve my problem. I am highlighting an address based on geocoder searched coordinates. This same functionality is working perfect on the click on building but I do not want to click on building rather just highlight the building based on searched coordinates. I am providing code below:

```
       map.addLayer(
          {
            id: "3d-buildings",
            source: "composite",
            "source-layer": "building",
            type: "fill",
            minzoom: 10,
            paint: {
              "fill-color": "#aaa",
            },
          },
          labelLayerId
        );

        map.addSource("currentBuildings", {
          type: "geojson",
          data: {
            type: "FeatureCollection",
            features: [],
          },
        });
        map.addLayer(
          {
            id: "highlight",
            source: "currentBuildings",
            type: "fill",
            minzoom: 15,
            paint: {
              "fill-color": "#f00",
            },
          },
          labelLayerId
        );
```

This below click working perfect

```
        map.on("click","3d-buildings", (e) => {
          map.getSource("currentBuildings").setData({
            type: "FeatureCollection",
            features: e.features,
          });
        });
```

I want the same features but not on click rather than on geocoder result coordinates:

```
        geocoder.on("result", (e) => {
          var coordinates = e.result.geometry.coordinates;
          const selectedFeatures = map.querySourceFeatures(coordinates, {
            layers: ["3d-buildings"],
          });
          console.log(selectedFeatures); //giving blank array, how can I get the features same as the onclick function is providing with additional parameter which is 3d-buildings

          map.getSource("currentBuildings").setData({
            type: "FeatureCollection",
            features: e.features,
          });
        });
```

Maybe I am wrong at some point in using querySourceFeature. Please direct me in right direction.